# Trouble with return statement in Node Async Await

Tags: node.js, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to write a query for DynamoDB and learn promises etc.  The console.log(resp.Items) returns the object that I am looking for so I think my query is formatted correctly.  I get a status 200 back with an empty object.

I have read up for a few days and tried to implement various changes to the code by nothing is returning the object resp.Items.  I am guessing the function is returning before the const is updated with the data but I am not sure why the console.log works.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB()

const getTechs = async () => {
  try {
    const resp = await dynamodb
      .query({
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':tech': { S: 'TECH#' },
        },
        KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :tech',
        TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
        ScanIndexForward: true,
      })
      .promise()
    console.log(resp.Items)

    if (!resp.Items) {
      return {
        error: 'No Techs in the DB',
      }
    }
    
    return {
      tech: resp.Items,
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error retrieving Tech List')
    console.log(error)
    return {
      error: 'Could not retrieve Tech List',
    }
  }
}
```

handler func

```js
const { makeHandler } = require('./utils')
const { getTechs } = require('../data')
// const { Tech } = require('../entities')

const inputSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    pathParameters: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        tech: { type: 'string' },
      },
      required: ['tech'],
    },
  },
  required: ['pathParameters'],
}

const handler = async (event) => {
  const { techs, error } = await getTechs()
  const statusCode = error ? 500 : 200
  const body = error ? JSON.stringify({ error }) : JSON.stringify({ techs })
  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
  }
}

module.exports.handler = makeHandler({ handler })
```

executeTransactWrite func

```js
const executeTransactWrite = async ({ tech, params }) => {
  const transactionRequest = tech.transactWriteItems(params)
  let cancellationReasons
  transactionRequest.on('extractError', (response) => {
    try {
      cancellationReasons = JSON.parse(
        response.httpResponse.body.toString()
      ).CancellationReasons
    } catch (err) {
      // suppress this just in case some types of errors aren't JSON parseable
      console.error('Error extracting cancellation error', err)
    }
  })
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transactionRequest.send((err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        err.cancellationReasons = cancellationReasons
        return reject(err)
      }
      return resolve(response)
    })
  })
}

module.exports = {
  executeTransactWrite,
```

makehandler func

```js
const middy = require('middy')
const {
  jsonBodyParser,
  validator,
  httpErrorHandler,
} = require('middy/middlewares')

const makeHandler = ({ handler, inputSchema }) =>
  middy(handler)
    .use(jsonBodyParser())
    .use(validator({ inputSchema }))
    .use(httpErrorHandler())

module.exports = { makeHandler }
```

Comment: Everything looks correct here. How is the `getTechs` function used?

Comment: I added the handler function that is being triggered by API gateway.  This code is being used in a lambda function.

Comment: Where is your `makeHandler` function?

Comment: Added the make handler function.  Sry about not including all the files upfront... lesson learned!

Comment: Why aren't you passing `inputSchema` to `makeHandler()`?

Comment: InputSchema was setup to build an object for a Post.  Since I am trying to do  a get request I left it out since I am not passing an object.  At least that was my thinking... following along with a book....

Comment: Does that make a difference if your `makeHandler` ends up using `validator({ inputSchema: undefined })`?

Comment: I think it does and this might very well be the problem.  Going to look into these helper functions more, I was too focused on the query function working and not looking into what was being returned to the other funcs.    Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Maybe just skip `makeHandler()` for this one to rule it out... `module.exports.handler = handler;`

Comment: Is the object key `tech` or `techs`? You've got inconsistent usage

Comment: It is supposed to be techs.  I changed it and that solved the issue.  I had const body = error ? JSON.stringify({ error }) : JSON.stringify({ techs }) but was passing it  return {
      tech: resp.Items,
    }.  I would not have figured this out, Thanks Again.

Comment: I'm not a fan of constantly wrapping / unwrapping objects. Personally, I'd have `getTechs()` return a promise that either resolves with `resp.Items` or rejects with an error message

Comment: I understand, and that would have avoided this entire issue.  I am going to refactor this code.  Your point of wrapping and unwrapping is very valid.  It is hard enough for a beginner to follow without the extra complexities here.  Lesson learned.